# Why do some chars appear smaller in Visual Studio 2019/2022?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

It's especially about those 2 chars: { and / 
They appear from time to time smaller then usual. Some times all { look tiny.
An example with /:

[image]

Notice the 1. and 4. / (which is standard size), and 2. and 3. one.

Another example with }:

[image]

Notice the last } and the one before (which is standard).

Are there any specific settings which I'm missing? Or is it a bug?

Comment: wow, that weird and looks like a bug! Maybe it's due to the different font settings for normal code and comments or other things that VS mixes up. I've never experienced it because I always unify settings like removing italics, bolds and setting all fonts to the same style but colors.

Comment: Are you using any extensions?

Comment: Not that I know of which could have this kind of side effect. But I'll try to enable/disable them one by one to see, if the problem vanishes.